# IIS Enable RPC Connections

Tags: zend-framework, iis, json-rpc

I'm trying to create a JSON RPC server in Zend Framework hosted on IIS. Connections to my server work fine using this example, taken from http://site1/request.html:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="js/jquery-1.3.min.js"></SCRIPT>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="js/json2.js"></SCRIPT>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="js/jquery.zend.jsonrpc.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var myApi = jQuery.Zend.jsonrpc({url: '/api/1.0/jsonrpc'});
            });
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have two sites hosted locally (on IIS 7.5), and the calls work fine to the RPC Server on the same domain - above the url is given as `'/api/1.0/jsonrpc'`.

If I change this to the url of a another site, e.g. `http://site2/api/1.0/jsonrpc` the calls fail.

I belive IIS is disallowing anonymous access for the RPC calls, hence why it works from a call made within the current 'doimain'.

Can anyone tell me how to make IIS play nice and allow these sort of requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to a cookie sent with the request. The domain doesn't match when the response comes back so nothing is returned. Time to rebuild!